double quotation marks when using ascii() function python
ascii('hi')
Out[23]: "'hi'"
ascii("hi")
Out[24]: "'hi'"

Why is it that when I use the ascii function I get single quotes wrapped in double quotes?

The double quotes are wrapped around the printed (displayed) string. The single quotes are added around the output of the ascii return value.

the function returns a string representation of the input string, which is essentially the same string enclosed in single quotes. These single quotes are then enclosed in double quotes because that's how Python represents strings.

Also, if you run this: chr(97), you will get 'a' as a result. So in IDLE, you will see: "'a'". You could always strip the single-quotes: ascii('hi').strip("'")

@MrP No, I think you’ve doubled that up too much.

See the docs what ascii does: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii. It’s essentially repr. Now see the duplicate linked above.
